# Damaging illusion area effect

Tags: ranged-attack, illusion, area-of-effect, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I am new to M&M (3rd edition) and am creating a mystic character whose primary powers are mental. I have taken the illusion power (all senses) at rank 5 (the maximum) and made it independent. I want to link a perception ranged damage effect so that the illusion physically damages those influenced by it. How does this work in a scene? Do characters roll against the illusion (insight check) to see if they are influenced and then again (will check) to see if they take damage? Does the damage element just work on a single character like a ranged attack or would all affected characters make a damage check? Thanks for any insight you can offer!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Justin: Is there anything more I can add to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

To get damage, you have to buy the Damage effect. You're likely looking at either a Perception or Area Damage effect so as to avoid needing to make attack checks. The Illusion Power Profile suggests Alternate Resistance (Will), Resistable (Will, successful resistance removes damage), and Variable Descriptor 2 to model all of the different sorts of damage possible via the illusion.

And, of course, your GM can decide whatever house rules make sense to them.